# Is using __name__ == "__main__" statements for purposes other than an entry point pythonic?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

Here is a python script that sends its output to different places depending on whether it was run interactively or imported as a module.

```
# main.py
def main():
    output = "... do some processing ..."
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print("sending output to stdout")
        #print(output)
    else:
        print("sending output to file")
        #write_to_file(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A different path runs depending on how the script is called:

```
$ python main.py
sending output to stdout

$ python
>>> import main
>>> main.main()
sending output to file
```

---

The code works as expected, but I feel like it could be a code smell. I can see reasons why multiple of these checks in a single script is both good and bad and I am looking for feedback as to whether or not this is pythonic.

### Reasons why it may be pythonic

1. There is precedent in other languages for using similar constructs (like `#ifdef DEBUG` in c++)
2. This method does not introduce another variable into main()'s parameter list (see #3 under Cons.)

### Reasons why it may be unpythonic

1. I have not seen multiple `if __name__ == "__main__":` statements in production code or in any code examples (although my search was not exhaustive.)
2. The [python 3 documentation for `__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) does not include any examples that promote this coding style. There are only mentions to the common way it is used. Exclusion from the doc does not mean it is bad, just that the style is uncommon.
3. The same objective can be achieved, probably with less confusion to newer python developers, by passing an argument such as `output="file"` to main()

I hope this question is not too opinion-based for SO. Feel free to quote from the Zen of Python to support your answer if you wish. I look forward to your feedback.

Comment: This type of question is offtopic on SO, take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: I'd suggest giving `main()` an argument with a default value (e.g. a filename to write to), then calling it with a different value from the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. This way you only need the one check to see if you're running as a script, and you can debug that script-like behavior by passing a non-default argument from other code if you need to.

Comment: @pvg Is there another stack exchange site that may be more appropriate? Or do I need to take this question to another site entirely?

Comment: I'm not really sure, maybe the software engineering might be worth checking out? Discussions about how 'pythonic' something is often get a little... talmudic, if potentially entertaining.